# Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code React native

Tags: react-native

i create the new React native 0.68 Project which is successfully build and run on xcode 13.3.1 but when i copy and past this project on another folder and run this project on xcode 13.3.1
then i am facing this error  and my OS is macos Monterey version 12.0.1.

```
 Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
    
    /bin/sh -c /Users/essmac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/NassauTennisMobileApp-hbuvecnapzaxwackghdwmndhemau/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/FBReactNativeSpec.build/Script-46EB2E00017C40.sh

i have tried some solution which not work for me 
solution 
delete pod 
install pod again 

Any one can help me
```

Comment: delete derived data and then try to run

Comment: any solution you find

Comment: i remove the spaces of folder name  where project is created example root folder name
is react native  => react-native